# is it ok to use value field in coroutines?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, coroutine

I have a flow that contains the user's info(as a single object). there are some operations, that need to access the mentioned flow, in a single-shot op. no observing, just reading the required info once.

I know there are `single()` and other functions that can do the thing, but my question is, is it ok to use `value` property of the flow instead of those functions?

the flow is a `StateFlow` so `value` is immutable and I want to access the field only in the view model so I'm not violating encapsulation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is it ok to use value property of the flow instead of those functions?

Yes, it's ok to do so. The purpose of a `StateFlow` is to expose a "current value" at all times, so it's a valid use case to want to access `.value` directly, especially for one-shot read-only operations.

It doesn't even violate encapsulation.

Comment: Yeah you're right it doesn't violate encapsulation. I meant, Generally speaking, this approach doesn't violate any serious principle.